Generate the model (mesh) rendered by open3d on the original image
Through the following code, I can save the rendered image of each frame on a pure white background according to a random perspective, such as Figure 1, but I want the model to be rendered at the corresponding position in the original image, just such as Figure 2. How can I do this?
Figure 1
enter image description here
Figure 2
enter image description here
This is my code
import argparse
import os
import json
import copy
import re
import open3d as o3d
import cv2
from pytorch3d.io import load_obj
import open3d.visualization.rendering as rendering
import numpy as np
o3d.utility.set_verbosity_level(o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Error)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-output', '--output', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-save', '--save', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

import utils as uts

# setting
os.makedirs(args.save, exist_ok=True)
_, face, _ = load_obj('apollo_deform/0.obj')
face = face.verts_idx.numpy()

# load class scales
scales = {}
for i in range(79):
    vert, _, _ = load_obj(f'car_models/{i}.obj')
    vert = vert.numpy()
    scales[i] = uts.call_scale(vert)

res_folder = os.path.join(args.output, 'res2')
mesh_folder = os.path.join(args.output, 'mesh2')
files = os.listdir(res_folder)
output_folder = os.path.join(args.save, 'output')
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

image_plane_files = []
image_3d_files = []
color_map = {}

# process each file
for file in files:
    if not file.endswith('.json'):
        continue

    file_path = os.path.join(res_folder, file)
    basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

    dts = json.load(open(file_path))
    mesh_file_path = os.path.join(mesh_folder, basename + '.npy')

    if not os.path.exists(mesh_file_path):
        continue

    meshes = np.load(mesh_file_path)
    colors = [np.random.random(3) * 255 for dt in dts]
    o3d_list = []
    colors = [color_map.get(dt['car_id'], np.random.random(3) * 255) for dt in dts]
    for dt, mesh, color in zip(dts, meshes, colors):
        if dt['score'] < 0.5:
            continue
        if dt['car_id'] not in color_map:
            color_map[dt['car_id']] = color
        mesh[:, [0, 1]] *= -1
        s = scales[dt['car_id']]
        ts = uts.call_scale(mesh)
        mesh = uts.project(np.array(dt['pose']), s / ts, mesh)
        print(mesh)
        o3d_mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh(vertices=o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(copy.deepcopy(mesh)),
                                             triangles=o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(face))
        o3d_mesh.paint_uniform_color(color / 255)
        o3d_mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
        o3d_list.append(o3d_mesh)

        # Export each car as an OBJ file
        obj_filename = os.path.join(args.save, f"{basename}_car_{dt['car_id']}.obj")
        o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh(obj_filename, o3d_mesh)

    # save rendered images
    vis = uts.VisOpen3D(width=1242, height=500, visible=False)
    for obj in o3d_list:
        vis.add_geometry(obj)
    vis.load_view_point("camera.json")
    # vis.run()
    # vis.save_view_point('camera.json')
    image_plane_path = os.path.join(args.save, f'{basename}.image_plane.png')
    vis.capture_screen_image(image_plane_path)
    image_plane_files.append(image_plane_path)


    vis.load_view_point("camera-3d1.json")
    #vis.run()
    image_3d_path = os.path.join(args.save, f'{basename}.3d.png')
    vis.capture_screen_image(image_3d_path)
    image_3d_files.append(image_3d_path)

    del vis
    print(f"Processed file: {file}")

print("ALL files processed")
raise SystemExit


I have tried changing the rendered pure white background image to a transparent background and then adding it to the original image, but I need to process the video, so this operation is time-consuming and labor-intensive and cannot guarantee that the corresponding mesh is in the corresponding position of the original image.
